Not able to read data from com port in raspberry Pi 3 b+ and I have installed windows 10 iot
I have created a simple program to read the data from com port,but not able to read the data from com port and the com port is showing in th device manager. Can anyone help me

help you with what? ... you did not say that you are doing and what you tried

I have created a simple.net application to read the data from com port and I have deploy that application on raspberry Pi,but now I am not able to read the data from com port . In device manager com port is displaying but it is not reading the data ,I tried to install all the drivers but still it is not working
